# Cannot coerce text to number

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a fundraising spreadsheet that will say whether funders are currently open or closed for applications. It should return Open if today's date falls within the funding window; otherwise it should say Closed. Rolling deadlines are always Open.

I would like for it to work regardless of the year, but I'm now getting the following error: "Function MONTH parameter 1 expects number values. But 'rolling' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." I don't understand why, as it recognizes the cells as non-text. Here's the demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GCiQAqsLsEQwgFYXigJPGj6XpZ9UB5uIIejWnmW6V4c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({"Status"; 
 IF(A2:A="",,IF(A2:A="rolling", "Open",
 IF(A2:A<=B2:B, IF(
 (DATEVALUE(A2:A)<=DATEVALUE(TODAY()))*
 (DATEVALUE(B2:B)>=DATEVALUE(TODAY())), "Open", "Closed"),
 "end date < start date")))})
```

[image]